# How to implement generic object check predicate that will adhere to an T interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code that represents two interfaces and two objects. The issue, however, is how to create a generic predicate function that checks if the passed object adheres to the mentioned interfaces. I tried other implementations of the predicate, but they showed false positives since in core the object should adhere to an interface rather than to other object.

```js
export const willObjectAdhereToInterface = <T>(item: any): item is T => {
  // Check for null and undefined only
  if (item === null || item === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  // Check it is an object
  if (typeof item !== 'object') {
    return false;
  }

  // Get the expected keys of type T
  const expectedKeys: Array<keyof T> = Object.keys({} as T) as Array<keyof T>;

  // Check if all keys of T are present in the item
  return expectedKeys.every((key) => key in item);
};



interface A {
  a1: string;
  a2: string;
}

interface B {
  b1: string;
  b2: string;
  diffrence1: number;
  diffrence2: number;
}
const a: A = {
  a1: 'a1',
  a2: 'a2',
 
};

const b: B = {
  b1: 'b1',
  b2: 'b2',
  diffrence1: 0,
  diffrence2: 1,
};

if(willObjectAdhereToInterface<A>(a)){
// a is deffinatly of A interface 
}

if(willObjectAdhereToInterface<B>(b)){
// a is deffinatly of B interface 
}


if(willObjectAdhereToInterface<A>(b)){
console.log(b.a1) // must show an error.
}
```

as for what i currently did is this 2 generic functions one will check for the object but it has to have required keys to check against (not so good) and the other is to check for set State action that uses the first function..

```js
// T will represent the interface of the state
export const isGenericObject = <T>(object: any, requiredFields: string[] /* Pass the keys */): object is Partial<T> | T => {
  // Check for null and undefined only
  if (object === null || object === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  // Check if object
  if (typeof object !== 'object') {
    return false;
  }

  // Retrieve keys from the item
  const keys = Object.keys(object);

  // Check if all required fields are present
  const hasAllRequiredFields = requiredFields.every((field) => keys.includes(field));

  return hasAllRequiredFields;
};

const isGenericSetState = <T>(object: any, setState: any): setState is Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>> => {
  // Check for null or undefined
  if (setState === null || setState === undefined) {
    return false;
  }

  // Check if setState has the expected type
  if (typeof setState !== 'function') {
    return false;
  }

  if (object !== undefined && isGenericObject(object, Object.keys(object))) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing runtime (JavaScript) and compile time (TS Types) code. **Interfaces do not exist in runtime** and therefore you cannot write code that will check if an object adheres to an interface.

If you want to check runtime objects, then the best option is the `isGenericObject` you wrote already with a small improvement by typing the required fields property:

```
const isGenericObject = <T>(object: any, requiredFields: (keyof T)[]): object is Partial<T> | T => {
```

There is no getting around this extra argument.

The only other thing you can do is convert interfaces to classes and then pass the class itself instead of a required fields array

```
const isGenericObject = <T>(object: any, ObjectClass: new () => T): object is Partial<T> | T => {
  const requiredKeys = Object.keys(new ObjectClass());
}
```

But this requires you to create a constructor for each type that will initialise all the required keys which IMO is worse than just creating the arrays.

---

There is one different approach you can take, but **only if you want the error in compile time and will NOT check agains objects you are not certain what they are**. And that is using `extends` to check if something is valid or not:

```
const asSupertype = <TSuper, T extends TSuper>(obj: T) => obj as TSuper;

// ...

if(asSupertype<A, typeof b>(b)) { // compiler will show error on typeof b
}
```